# Oracle Select counts/ values from rows into columns

Tags: oracle, join, count

I have been trying to get some results from rows to be presented into columns.

Table is like,

```
Event_ID
User ID
Event_Type (Call,App)
...
```

A user can have multiple events of type, either Call or Appointment. I want to list the results as

```
User_ID      Calls_Count      Appointments_Count
01            4                10
02            0                12
```

I have managed to write a query to get the desired results, but if a user has either no Call or Appointments, the record does not appear in results.

```
select 
distinct(e.user_id),
Call.cc as Call_Count,
App.ac as App_Count

from events e,
(select user_id,event_type,count(user_id) as cc from events c where event_type = 'Call' group by user_id,event_type) Call,
(select user_id,event_type,count(user_id) as ac from events a where event_type = 'App' group by user_id,event_type) App

where e.user_id = Call.user_id
and e.user_id = App.user_id

order by user_id asc
;
```

How can I convert this query to use `join`, so that it returns the desired results, or is there a better way to achieve the same.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 11 version:

```
select * from events 
  pivot (count(1) for (event_type) in ('App' Apps, 'Call' Calls))
  order by user_id
```

Older versions:

```
select user_id,
    count(case when event_type = 'App' then 1 end) Apps,
    count(case when event_type = 'Call' then 1 end) Calls
  from events 
  group by user_id
  order by user_id
```

---

Edit: for solution with `pivot` it's good to limit columns to these which interests us at first, like here:

```
select * from (select user_id, event_type from events)
  pivot (count(1) for (event_type) in ('App' Apps, 'Call' Calls))
  order by user_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7838/1)

Comment: I have Oracle 11g Express Edition on my machine, but the query you have shared for Oracle 11 version does give the desired results, however the second one works perfectly as I wanted, Can you share how to update the first query to get the same results

Comment: thanks for your effort, it does work now and thanks for showing the alternate and better way to improve my query :)